# How do I restrict the results of a facebook graph search to status updates?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The following query will get all public posts about the word invested.

```
https:graph.facebook.com/search?q=invested&type=post&fields=id,type,message
```

however, only about half have `type=status`. The rest are links videos and pictures.
Substituting type=status is invalid.

[Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) seems to offer a solution, but my first interpretation of it is incorrect.

```
https:graph.facebook.com/search?q=invested&type=post&fields=id,type(status),message
```

What is the correct way to get only the status messages?

Before you say it, I know I could just filter them on my end, but I'm looking into this solution because it would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe field expansion will work here. If there is a way to filter on a specific type of sub-field, using field expansion I haven't found it yet.

An FQL query of the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table is the tool for the job with the mystery [CONTAINS()](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12630401/documentation-for-contains-in-fql) operator. Status updates are type 46.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, type, message FROM stream 
    WHERE CONTAINS('invested') AND type=46
```

If you wanted to get all posts that have a message, regardless of type, you could replace `type=46` with `strlen(message)>0`

Comment: Thanks. I would have never discovered that.